# Construct an analytic function given a countably infinite set of coordinate pairs.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, lagrange-interpolation

Suppose we have a function $f(x), x\in\mathbb Z$.

Is there any way to construct an analytic function $g(x), x\in\mathbb R$, such that:
$$
f(x) = g(x), x\in \mathbb Z
$$